# Impedance and Source Transformation

Tags: ac

[image]

For this problem, if we try to perform source transformation, we get different results based on which side of the circuit we decide to transform. For instance, if we transform the right side of the circuit (the current source and the resistor in parallel) we get a voltage source of 10V.

But, if we transform the leftside of the circuit (the equivalent impedance being -3j) we get a voltage source of -6j.

This affects the current we get for the entire circuit and hence affects the power calculations as well.

I'm wondering why this situation happens and if there's a flaw in my understanding of source transformation that causes mistake.

Comment: Use current division to calculate current in each branch.  Then compare result to what you get using source transformation.  You can edit your question to show your work.

Answer (score 3):

Once you transform a current source in parallel with an impedance to a voltage source in series with an impedance, you cannot map the new series impedance to be equivalent to the old parallel impedance.

Taking this to the limits; you could transform the current source in parallel with **both impedances** to a voltage source in series with the parallel arrangement of **both impedances** like this: -

[image]

And clearly there is no current flow at all. So, be careful about what meaning you extract when doing transformations.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the current source and the reactances to a voltage source with a series reactance -3j Ohm you can use it to calculate the current of the resistor. The rest of the circuit is replaced by the equivalent and do not reflect what current the reactances have in the original circuit.

If you convert the current source and the resistor to a voltage source with a series resistor 5 Ohm you can use it to calculate the current of the reactances. The rest of the circuit is replaced by the equivalent and do not reflect what current the resistor has in the original circuit.

To stay in truth member relayman357  has written about 10 hours ago a comment which suggested you to find the same by yourself.